# Grub stuck loading kernel

Tags: debian, system-installation, grub2, ssd

I recently installed an SSD and have been trying to install Debian on it. For a few reasons it has been difficult on this machine; at the moment I've installed everything but it is failing to boot. Whenever I try to manually boot my install grub freezes after: `linux /boot/vmlinuz... root=/dev/sda1` This is the second install where this issue has occurred.

In case it's relevant, in the past when I'd install debian I would always have to chroot from a live-cd or old install and install my video card driver. If not grub would freeze like it is doing now, although I never tried manually booting so I'm not sure it was failing at this step. Of course before trying to boot this time I followed all of the steps that have worked before.

I'm not getting any debug information. Is there perhaps a verbose mode for grub or does anyone have something I can try?

Edit: as an experiment I copied the kernel and initramfs to my other drive and tried booting from those. It brought me to the initramfs prompt where when I try to manually mount sda1 it tells me no such file or directory.

**Clarification:** Above when I saw manually boot, I mean that I'm in grub console trying to type something like

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
grub> boot
```

But grub stops responding after I load either the kernel or the initrd from the ssd.

**UPDATE**

I retried what I did in the edit above and it is successfully booting now without going to the initramfs prompt. (perhaps I had a typo somewhere before) I'm not making this a solution because GRUB is only able to load the kernel and initrd from my second drive and not my ssd.

Comment: 1) Are you perhaps missing an `initramfs`?  2) Are you sure your `root` partition is on `/dev/sda1`?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Grub freezes before I can load the initramfs and under grub my ssd is hd0 and my old install even has the ssd under sda.

Comment: try booting with removed `quiet` kernel parameter, and the boot sequence will be more verbose.

Comment: @Sircer loading the kernel (off the ssd) into memory is when it freezes. That is before I execute boot.

Comment: Set up a gparted usb, and ```fsck``` the filesystems, as well as checking that the partitions are still there

Comment: @Parallaxbeta fsck says it's is clean, on my working install I can chroot into it and everything works, grub can even ls the files in that partition.

Comment: what happens if you `chroot` into it, and then `update-grub`?

Comment: @Parallaxbeta It doesn't throw any error. I've updated grub on both hard drives with the same issue regardless of which drive I boot to.

Comment: If uninstalling and reinstalling the linux kernel and grub don't work, then the problem has to be hardware based.

Comment: `cat /etc/fstab`  `cat /etc/default/grub` this with sudo or as root `parted -l`  `lsblk -f` `dmidecode -t 0`  and `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS` ans `lsblk -f`post it to https://gist.github.com please.

Comment: @Bahamut https://gist.github.com/DavidBrandly/6fba4e426c0c5857b77391c642423681#file-grub-stuck-loading-kernel

Answer (score 1):

The installation guide lists a number of optional [boot parameters](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s03.html.en) you can add to the Grub command line and see if anything helps.  There is also an alternate Debian CD with different drivers which you could try.

The troubleshooting section of the installation guide is several pages long and points to various other sections for details; you will probably want to read at least the main parts: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch05s04.html

Comment: Did you not read the comments above? Grub freezes when loading the kernel. How will boot parameters help if the kernel never in memory?

Comment: @David - Loading the kernel is a quite quick action.  The kernel can pretty much be the thing that is freezing.  Between the kernel entering the memory and outputting the first thing to the terminal is a long road, and parameter parsing do happen in that time.  It takes time before the kernel figures out how to output to the terminal.

Comment: @grochmal by manually boot I mean that I'm typing the commands into grub console. Editing question to clarify that. So grub freezes after I tell it to load the kernel and before I tell it to boot.

Comment: @David I don't see what makes you think that kernel parameters can't help. They'd go in the `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic ...` line. And no, don't assume people have read the comments. If something is relevant, you need to add it to your question.

Comment: @ḾádḾőíśéĺĺé this isn't really answering the question though. You're just providing resources. Could you explain *which* kernel parameters you think could help? How to add them? Your answer needs to be helpful even if the links no longer work. Please copy the relevant information and include it here.

Answer (score 0):

change your /etc/fstab

```
UUID=0784c0e3-d4c7-4ae4-ab48-0cd3b4fb3198 /  ext4   errors=remount-ro 0       1 

UUID=28c088fc-5045-4155-89f3-f1e43d903d4f  /tmp  ext4  defaults  0    2
UUID=5b784a02-4f23-4d10-898b-833dd49f815c  /home  ext4 defaults  0    2
```

Your /etc/default/grub is almost emty?

```
dpkg -l | grep grub | awk '{print $2}' | xargs apt install --reinstall -y
```

This will reinstall all your Grub-packages. Then  `update-grub`

Answer (score -1):

I was working on an ASUS laptop with an unusual bios. It really was designed to keep people from using Linux.

I also had the grub command line "linux " just hang when trying to boot off a USB drive. I had tried doing *alot* of BIOS changes.

My USB key has an LED so I can see when it's doing reads/writes. It was just never load the file, or sometimes maybe, but then initrd  would never work.

I reset the BIOS to factory defaults and it worked. I think some of these stupid AMI/Pheonix BIOSes are so damned broken (BIOS/firmware engineers in China almost exclusively use and develop with Windows).

Comment: You seem to be complaining a lot instead of just stating: "Try resetting your BIOS to factory defaults and see if that works", which is a guess at a solution and not a solution.